# Is there complete cardano-cli documentation?

Tags: cardano-cli, datum, documentation

Hello all I can find is the cardano-cli help and
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/cardano-node-cli-reference.md/
I am trying to get information on things like what --tx-out-datum-embed-file FILE does

Comment: This is a cop-out answer, but in my experience there surest place to go for answers is to read the source code directly.

Answer (score 3):

The flag `--tx-out-datum-embed-file FILE` allows you to embed the **[datum data](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/how-to-retrieve-the-datum-added-with-the-option-tx-out-datum-embed-file-from-th)** on the transaction, not the **datum hash** like using that flag `--tx-out-datum-hash-file FILE`.

```
cardano-cli transaction build --tx-out-datum-embed-file DATUM.json
```

> According to [this web page](https://giters.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3472), the definition is vague: The script datum to embed in the tx for this output, in the given JSON file. The file must follow the special JSON schema for script data.

I totally agree with you that a topic on `datums`/`redeemers` in JSON format for Tx is undocumented. However, I managed to find a very interesting GitHub post, which, I hope, will shed a light on some unclear things – **[Here it is](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/16)**. Unfortunately, that's all I could find on this topic.

Comment: I Appreciate the reference. I still wouldn't know how to actually create a json file that can be directly uploaded from these. Like would I put the path to an arbitrary file in the fields value of another json file, or do I have to encode to cbor first. Its all very incomplete

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to learn this too. I could not find any further documentation other than the `cardano-cli` command help. This is pretty extensive and useful. Every command argument seems to have built-in help. So, for instance, to get help with building a transaction, issue the command `cardano-cli transaction build`. The help for this includes some info on the `--tx-out-datum-embed-file FILE` arguments.